# How To call Service in Controller using @Autowired Annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

**Here i'm trying to implement simple crud operation in spring-hibernate. For that i have seperated the service layer and Dao layer.**

**EmployeeService interface**

```
package com.kalam.service;

import com.kalam.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {

    public void addEmployee(Employee emp);

    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp);

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp,int id);

}
```

**EmployeeDao interface**

```
package com.kalam.dao;

import com.kalam.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeDao {

public void addEmployee(Employee emp);

    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp);

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp,int id);

}
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl class**

**Here i wanted to ask that does "@Service("employeeService")" this line creates bean with id employeeService?**

```
package com.kalam.serviceimpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.kalam.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;
import com.kalam.service.EmployeeService;

@Service("employeeService")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{


    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        employeeDao.addEmployee(emp);

    }

    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp, int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**EmployeeDao class**

```
package com.kalam.daoimpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.kalam.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;

@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {
    @Autowired
     SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }



    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(emp);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }



    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
         Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(emp);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

    }



    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp, int id) {
         Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, new Integer(id));
            if(null != employee){
                session.delete(emp);
                                }
       session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

**And finally the most important hibernate-cfg.xml file (from where i think the errors are coming.)**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Activate Spring annotation support -->
<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.serviceimpl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.daoimpl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.model"/>

<!-- DataSource configurationt -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kalamdb"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
    </bean>  

   <bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>


 <bean id="employeeDaoImpl" class="com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl">    
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
       </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    </beans>
```

**I got the following error when i run the program.**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kalamController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kalam.service.EmployeeService com.kalam.controller.KalamController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1694)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1684)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kalam.service.EmployeeService com.kalam.controller.KalamController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more
```

**Here i'm sharing my approaches to solve the problem.**

**1. I tried to change component scanning in three ways**

A. `<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam"/>`

B. By keeping all package in seperate scanning:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.serviceimpl"/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.daoimpl"/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.model"/>
```

C. By merging all of them in one scan:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller,com.kalam.serviceimpl,com.kalam.daoimpl,com.kalam.model" />
```

**2. I try to make bean of EmployeeServiceImpl in hibernate-cfg.xml as follows**

```
 <bean id="employeeDaoImpl"class="com.kalam.serviceimpl.EmployeeServiceImpl">    
         <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>
```

And inject in kalam controller as follow

```
@Autowired
EmployeeDaoImpl employeeDaoImpl
```

**3. Also i tried  to inject EmployeeService in controller without defining the bean for EmployeeService and EmployeeServiceImpl in hibernate-cfg.xml as follows**

```
@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService
```

**4. My last important doubt is that does "@Service("employeeService")" code in EmployeeServiceImpl creates a bean? so that we can use**

```
@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService
```

**in controller class to call the service method in controller class. Here once again i wanted to highlight the point that i'm separating the service and dao layer.**

**Tell me  how can i enable to use  @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService directly into controller class. i know i'm trying to mix xml and annotation approach. Bt its legal  I'm too much nervous as i waste lots of time to resolve this error. Please help me. Thank you. Thank you.**

Comment: Add @Service("employeeService") on EmployeeService class rather than EmployeeServiceImpl

Comment: A Service is definitely not a JavaBean. Beans have a `constructor` and encapsulate methods. They also implement `Serializable`. You also need to remove your service from your application context in your `hibernate-cfg.xml`.

Comment: @Afridi as per your suggestion i add @Service("employeeService") on EmployeeService. Still getting the same error.